# NetBeans builds to c root instead of project folder

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I recently moved my NetBeans projects to a new laptop and have run into this problem. When I 'Clean & Build' my project two new folders are created, c:\build and c:\dist, and the classes and jar etc. are placed in them instead of in {project-folder}\build and {project-folder}\dist.

This is where the build.dir and dist.dir are set in the project's build.xml

```
<property name="build.dir" value="\build"/>
<property name="build.classes.dir" value="\build\classes"/>
<property name="build.test.classes.dir" value="\build\test\classes"/>
<property name="build.test.results.dir" value="\build\test\results"/>
<property name="dist.dir" value="\dist"/>
<property name="dist.javadoc.dir" value="\dist\javadoc"/>
<property name="build.classes.excludes" value=""/>
<property name="dist.jar" value="\dist\build.jar"/>
```

This is the build output;

> ant -f "E:\My Projects\NetBeans\Java_5x" -Dnb.internal.action.name=rebuild clean jar
>   init:
>   deps-clean:
>   Updating property file: C:\build\built-clean.properties
>   Deleting directory C:\build
>   clean:
>   init:
>   deps-jar:
>   **Created dir: C:\build**
>   Updating property file: C:\build\built-jar.properties
>   Created dir: C:\build\classes
>   Created dir: C:\build\empty
>   **Compiling 116 source files to C:\build\classes**
>   Copying 116 files to C:\build\classes

Anyone got any ideas as to why this may be happening?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the leading slashes from all your properties.

```
<property name="build.dir" value="build"/>
<property name="build.classes.dir" value="build\classes"/>
<property name="build.test.classes.dir" value="build\test\classes"/>
<property name="build.test.results.dir" value="build\test\results"/>
<property name="dist.dir" value="dist"/>
<property name="dist.javadoc.dir" value="dist\javadoc"/>
<property name="build.classes.excludes" value=""/>
<property name="dist.jar" value="dist\build.jar"/>
```

You can see this yourself if you write a test method:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println(new File("/build").getCanonicalPath());
}
```

The leading slash indicates that it's supposed to be at the root of the working directory's device, even on Windows.